# How do I connect with a computer in a network sharing the same IP

Tags: discussion

OK, I'm probably the worst judge of on-topic-ness here, but I do feel that [this one](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/6357/33) ought to be OK.  He is obviously using a home router, but his question is more about protocol operation than "how do I make my home network do X?"

Answer (score 4):

Part of the beauty of the SE is that the community makes decisions for their own sites, so feel free to express your views as it may change how we run the site.

This specific site was created as a place for network professionals to interact.  While we are welcome at ServerFault (which is targeted at professional systems administrators), it isn't known as a "networking" destination and most network professionals don't find much benefit in sifting through all the server issues to find the occasional network question (at least on a regular basis).

In this case, as Mike has pointed out, this question is actually off topic because it violates two of our distinctions between on/off topic.

While the concepts of the question may not be explicitly off topic, in this case it is the context that is important.  While some of the bigger and older SE sites may let something like this slide occasionally, we aren't there yet.  There are two primary reasons that I believe makes this question not fit on this site currently:

1. We are trying to grow the community, but to do so we need to make sure we continue to maintain quality that will attract the individuals at which this site is targeted.
2. As members of the larger SE community, we want users to find answers that help them. Speaking for myself, when I answer a question here, I make assumptions about the knowledge level of the audience.  When I answer on another site such as SuperUser, I don't have the same assumptions.  In this case, this may result in answers here that are not as helpful for the OP as the same question asked on SuperUser.

Comment: It just seems to me that if approximately one third to half of the questions asked here are off-topic, then there must be a larger issue. When people see "network engineering" they ask network related questions. Perhaps you should change the name of the site to "Professional Network Engineering" or something like that.

Comment: I don't really think that changing the name of the site helps; Joe user just sees a site full of experts and wants to ask there.

Comment: @Ron, again the community chose the name, not me.  There are discussions both here on meta and on Area51 from before the site launch.  However, I think this is less of a problem than it seems currently.  Other professional oriented communities have a large number of off topic closures, but they also have larger communities and produce more on topic posts. I also believe this will always be worse for us to some degree simply because we will have the word network in our site name and people will try to ask their network questions here.

Comment: _"I make assumptions about the knowledge level of the audience."_ I completely agree with this.  This totally isn't a "My computer won't turn on, fix it for me" site.  This is a site dedicated to professionals that oftentimes have really complex issues.

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of whether the user is at home or at work...

Quoting the help center, on / off topic link...

> Note: All questions about RESIDENTIAL/HOME networking and CONSUMER-grade equipment, are explicitly OFF-topic.

and

> Off-topic: Users / Customers of Enterprise or Service Provider Netrworks
>
> Questions from end-users of enterprise/service provider networks are off-topic. There is no point in assisting an end-user since there isn't anything they can do (if the problem is a corporate networking or ISP issue). If the problem is the user's, they should ask on Super User

Comment: I understand your point, but my opinion is that one of the benefits of places like this is education.  I would rather answer with an explanation of what is going on, since it does help all the "real network people" here as well.

Comment: [SU] is a great place for education too... and, you even have an account there

Comment: I don't expect you to agree with me, but I wanted to register my dissent.  Not everyone is as clever as I am to look in two places.